# Эффективное использование QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

На [странице справки](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) для `QNetworkAccessManager` в разделе **Detailed Description** приводится следующее замечание:

> Note: QNetworkAccessManager queues the requests it receives. The
>   number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol.
>   Currently, for the HTTP protocol on desktop platforms, 6 requests are
>   executed in parallel for one host/port combination.

Означает ли это, что в случае различия в комбинации хост/порт или отправке запросов, скажем, на два различных адреса, запросы будут исполнены последовательно?

---

Для `QNetworkRequest` определён такой интересный [атрибут](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#Attribute-enum), как `HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute`. Связан ли этот атрибут с механизмом параллельной отправки запросов, например, с условием соответствия единой комбинации хост/порт?

---

У `QNetworkAccessManager` имеется метод предварительного подключения к серверной стороне на указанном порту:

```
void QNetworkAccessManager
    ::connectToHost(const QString &hostName, quint16 port = 80)
```

Как я понимаю, это может отчасти или даже полностью нивелировать время, затрачиваемое на резолвинг доменного имени и так называемый [TCP handshake](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP). Каково количество подобных подключений будет являться наиболее эффективным? Должно ли это число соответствовать количеству разных комбинаций хост/порт или оно должно соответствовать количеству каналов (6 штук), которые организует `QNetworkAccessManager` при подключении к одной комбинации хост/порт?

Comment: У Вас очень специфичные вопросы, я бы задал их на форуме Qt, там больше шансов получить ответ. И то, я сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Означает ли это, что в случае различия в комбинации хост/порт или отправке запросов, скажем, на два различных адреса, запросы будут исполнены последовательно?

Вы хотели сказать "паралельно", а не последовательно?

Данное условие нужно понимать так - не более 6 запросов на одно серверное подключение (хост:порт). Да, апач/нджинкс может слушать одновременно на 2 портах, тогда как бы получается 12 запросов. Но с клиентской стороны это очень сложно узнать.

В случае различных хостов запросы делаются "в паралель" (лично проверял на нескольких проектах). В случае различных портов не проверял, но думаю, что будет также работать.  Правда, когда хосты виртуальные (и сидят за одним айпи), то вроде оно все таки не превышает лимита в 6 запросов. Но здесь у меня слишком противоречивые результаты. Поэтому, нужно будет отдельно поисследовать это вопрос и разобраться - хост - это доменное имя или айпи.

> HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute

Эта штука позволяет оправлять несколько запросов, не дожидаясь ответов сразу. Естественно, сервер должен поддерживать http/1.1. То есть, отправляется много запросов, а потом ожидаем ответы, но это все в пределах одного соединения. Запросы на различные хосты не могут использовать эту фичу. Особенный выиграш от этой опции наступает тогда, когда запросы мелкие, независимые и их много, а сеть и их обработка жутко медленная.

> Как я понимаю, это может отчасти или даже полностью нивелировать время, затрачиваемое на резолвинг доменного имени и так называемый TCP handshake. ?

да, может. А может и нет:)

> Каково количество подобных подключений будет являться наиболее эффективным?

А тут все очень специфично. Возможно, что выиграша совсем не будет. Выиграш будет в том случае, если Вам нужно будет выполнить очень быстро запрос (например, пользовать прокручивает список и нужно подгрузить очередную порцию данных или он играет в игру на бирже, где нужно очень быстро реагировать и задержка в 0.3 секунды может стоить состояния) - в этом случае есть смысл сделать преконнект.

А если нужно просто выполнить один-два запроса, то тут что делай преконнект, что не делай - разницы не будет. Потому что первый запрос все равно выполнит этот самый преконнект.

Как всегда, в подобных случаях помогают бенчмарки. Мне известен один случай, когда человек делал что то типа ботов-краулеров и его спросили, каким образом он настраивает конфиг на максимальную производительность. После долгих расспросов выяснилось, что он вначале запускает специальный тестовый скрпипт, который проганят программу при различных настройках и выбирает максимум. Да, этот скрипт иногда  работал по несколько суток, но зато потом выжимал с серверов все соки.

Comment: Спасибо. Немного непонятно по первому подвопросу. Шесть запросов выполняются параллельно при отправке на один и тот же хост/порт. Но в тоже самое время, как я понял, нет ограничения в количестве для параллельного выполнения, если целевые хосты в запросах отличаются между собой. Тогда, получается, ограничение на 6 параллельных запросов - это по сути ограничение именно серверной стороны?

Comment: Просто делать больше 6 параллельных запросов на один сервер в большинстве случаев лишено смысла. Сервер вряд ли больше обработает. А вот если наша цель ддос, тогда это уже на другой форум:-)

Comment: Нет, ни в коем случае. Вопрос о 6-ти запросах возник по причине именно наличия такого лимита, как такового и может быть переформулирован на что-то вроде: "А с чего это именно 6, а не 5 или 7, или ещё какое число?". "Сервер вряд ли больше обработает" параллельных запросов с одного соединения - это, получается, специальное искусственное ограничение в целях безопасности на серверной стороне, поскольку тех же параллельных запросов, но с разных клиентских хостов может быть на порядки больше. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Почему решили, что именно 6 - не знаю. Но вроде где то в документации nginx видел эту же цифру. Даже если допустим разрешить не 6, а 100 то это никак  не поможет (в большинстве случаев). Просто запросы будут скапливаться в очереди на сервере, а не на клиенте. А ответы все равно придут с той же скоростью (а может даже медленее, так как на сервере память будет забита запросами).